# Updating html table on javascript events

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

When loading data from a json file to a table is supposed to update those cells with colors depending the data of each cell.

My color changing script works but not in the intended way, this is what happens, first it loads the data from the json file but the colors of the cells doesn't change until i refresh the page.

that's when i use the **onload()**  event, using the **onchange()** doesn't work in anyway.

the trick i'm using now is having the **onload()** event replaced with **onmouseover="colorCeldas()"** and  **onmouseout="colorCeldas()"**.

But what i can do to avoid using that 'dirty' trick?

the html:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="App">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
  <script src= "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
  <title>Dashboard</title>

   <script src="./scripts/json_load.js"></script>   <!--script que cargar archivo json-->
   <script src="./scripts/color_celda.js"></script> <!--script que cambia color de las celdas -->
  <link rel = "stylesheet"   type = "text/css"   href = "./css/style.css" />  <!--css con colores de celdas -->
  </head>
<body onload="colorCeldas()" onmouseover="colorCeldas()" onmouseout="colorCeldas()">

  <!--Panel-->
 <div class="container" ng-controller="tablaCtrl" >

       <!--tabla con indicadores-->
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <fieldset style="border:1px solid black;">

                   <table class="table"  id="tablaIndicador" style="border-spacing: 10px; border-collapse: separate;">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Oferta</th>
                        <th>Demanda</th>
                        <th>Seguridad</th>
                        <th>Comunidad <br>Receptora</th>
                        <th>Mercadotecnia</th>
                        <th>Accesibilidad</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr ng-repeat="pueblo in pueblos"  style="color:white">
                        <td>{{pueblo.oferta}}</td>
                        <td>{{pueblo.demanda}}</td>
                        <td>{{pueblo.seguridad}}</td>
                        <td>{{pueblo.comunidad}}</td>
                        <td>{{pueblo.mercadotecnia}}</td>
                        <td>{{pueblo.accesibilidad}}</td>
                    </tr>
                    </table>

            </fieldset>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

the scripts

color_celda.js

```
function colorCeldas() {


var table = document.getElementById('tablaIndicador'),
    cells = table.getElementsByTagName('td');
var val;

for (var i = 0, len = cells.length; i < len; i++) {

   val= parseInt(cells[i].innerHTML,10);

      if (val > 75 && val <= 100) { //verde

          $(cells[i]).addClass('verdeBg')


        } else if (val >= 50 && val <= 75) { //naranja

            $(cells[i]).addClass('naranjaBg')


        } else if (val >= 0 && val < 50) { //rojo

            $(cells[i]).addClass('rojoBg')


        } else  { // sin datos gris

          $(cells[i]).addClass('grisBg')

        }

    }

}
```

the json file loader script

```
var App = angular.module('App', []);

App.controller('tablaCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get('pueblos.json')
       .then(function(res){
          $scope.pueblos = res.data;                
        });
});
```

Comment: Do you have a fiddle or a code example?

Comment: please paste your code, this is just html  and javascript. What do you mean with "first it loads the data from the json file".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AngularJS is a frontend framework. It is a good practice to avoid adding DOM manipulations inside the controllers, all the DOM manipulation must be inside the template or in [Directives](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) codes.

> **Controllers should not reference DOM**,
> Should Have view behavior,
> What should happen if user do X,
> Where do I get X from

In this case, the `onLoad` function is executed before the pueblos data arrive from the server, and before angular made the changes to the UI. Resuming when the function colorCeldas the DOM is empty.

The best way of do this is to put all your code on the template.

put this code on every cell with the right value

```
<td ng-class="valueColor(pueblo.oferta)">{{pueblo.oferta}}</td>
```

and add this method to the controller

```
$scope.valueColor = function (val){

  if (val > 75 && val <= 100) { //verde
    return 'verdeBg';
  } else if (val >= 50 && val <= 75) { //naranja
    return 'naranjaBg';
  } else if (val >= 0 && val < 50) { //rojo
    return 'rojoBg';
  } else  { // sin datos gris
    return 'grisBg';
  }
}
```